# How to access auto-generated github page?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have auto-generated a github page according to the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator). Now I have a new branch called `gh-pages`.

I don't really get the next step, can I host the generated page on github ? or do I need to deploy it on my own web server ?
Do I need to merge the page branch with my master branch ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer [here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages). To access the page go to `username.github.com/projectname`. Any change you make to the `gh-pages` branch will be reflected there.

Comment: There is also a link published in a repo's Settings > Github Pages.

Comment: `username.github.com/projectname` is deprecated, now is using `.io` : `username.github.io/projectname`

Answer (score 0):

Your page will not be available until the full build process has finished. You can view this process via the 'Action' tab.
[image]